# multiple httpbasic authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to do a multiple authentication configuration for staffs and students but every time i enter the student matriculation number and password, i get unauthorized but when i input the staff email and password i get authenticated

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class UserConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/users/**")
                    .permitAll().anyRequest()
                    .authenticated().and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }

        @Bean
        public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
            authenticationManagerBuilder
                    .userDetailsService(customUserDetailService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }

        @Bean
        CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
            return source;
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class StudentConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


        @Autowired
        private CustomStudentDetailService customStudentDetailService;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/student/**")
                    .permitAll().anyRequest()
                    .authenticated().and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder studentPasswordEncoder(){
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }


        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationProvider studentAuthenticationProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            provider.setPasswordEncoder(studentPasswordEncoder());
            provider.setUserDetailsService(customStudentDetailService);
            return provider;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(customStudentDetailService);
            auth.authenticationProvider(studentAuthenticationProvider());
        }
    }
}
```

customerStudentDetailService.java

```
@Service
public class CustomStudentDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    private StudentDao studentDao;

    public CustomStudentDetailService(StudentDao studentDao){
        this.studentDao = studentDao;
    }


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String matricNumber) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Student student =  this.studentDao.findStudentByMatricNumber(matricNumber);
        CustomStudentDetail studentDetail = null;
        if(student != null){
            studentDetail = new CustomStudentDetail();
            studentDetail.setStudent(student);
        }else{
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not exist with student id" +matricNumber);
        }
        return studentDetail;
    }
}
```

customerUserDetailService.java

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserDao userDao;


    public  CustomUserDetailService(UserDao userDao){
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = this.userDao.findUserByUserEmail(email);
        CustomUserDetail userDetail  =null;
        if(user !=null){
            userDetail= new CustomUserDetail();
            userDetail.setUser(user);
        }else{
            throw  new UsernameNotFoundException("user not exist with email: " +email);
        }
        return userDetail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `CustomStudentDetailService` has both a `userDao` and a `studentDao` at the moment; that's a design smell.

Comment: it does not have userDao